# Tensorflow 1.9 and raspberry pi zero w?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I want to know if Raspberry Pi Zero is able to run the new tensorflow 1.9 ?

Comment: Raspberry Pi Zero : TensorFlow 2.1.0 설치 (Python 3.7)
출처: https://bluexmas.tistory.com/1046 [파란크리스마스]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, TensorFlow 1.9 supports the Pi—as stated on the TensorFlow blog, in the article [TensorFlow 1.9 Officially Supports the Raspberry Pi](https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-1-9-officially-supports-the-raspberry-pi-b91669b0aa0):

> Thanks to a collaboration with the Raspberry Pi Foundation, we’re now happy to say that the latest 1.9 release of TensorFlow can be installed from pre-built binaries using Python’s pip package system! If you’re running Raspbian 9 (stretch), you can install it by running these two commands from a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
> pip3 install tensorflow
> ```

Be sure to use Python 3 and `pip3` as the pre-built packages are **only** for Python 3. If you use Python 2, your Pi will attempt to build all of the packages itself, which will take a *very* long time.

No guarantees are made about how well TensorFlow will work on the Zero, though—probably, not very well. The Zero has very limited resources, but you don't have to compile the packages, at the very least, so it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: I tried it on a Zero. The `hello world` example worked fine, but the first example from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/ I tried ran into memory problems. And ATM there is an issue with one of required packages. You should run `pip3 install grpcio==1.14.1`before installing tensorflow, otherwise the source for grpcio will be downloaded and compiled, which can take a while on a Pi0.